# In Java, how to only pick or filter files created between during a specific time period

Tags: java, file-io, filter, timestamp

In a folder where many files exist, I want to be able to read only those files which were created between a certain timestamp duration.

Requirement is something like:
- from location \web\data\ read only those files which are created between `12/15/2013 11:55:00 PM` and `12/26/2013 11:54:00 PM`.

Here is the piece of my existing code which need above filter:

```
File directory = new File(fileLoc);
String[] myFiles;
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
   public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName2) {
      return fileName2.startsWith(filePrefix);
}};

myFiles = directory.list(filter);
if(myFiles.length < 1) {
   System.out.println("No files found");
   return;
}

String filePath = "";
for (String fileName:myFiles) {
try {
    filePath = fileLoc+fileName;
    System.out.println("Parsing:" + filePath);
    readFileAsString(filePath);
} 
catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: You already using `FilenameFilter`, along with `fileName2.startsWith(filePrefix)` add a check for created-date as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Ben, @Nicolas-R, @Basil-Bourque.
With all your inputs(use of listFiles, change in filter logic & using joda), this is what I finally made & works like charm:

```
File directory = new File(fileLoc);
FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (!file.isFile()) return false;
        LocalDateTime dt = new LocalDateTime(file.lastModified());
        if (dt!=null && (interval.contains(dt.toDateTime()) || interval.getEnd().isEqual(dt.toDateTime())))
            if (file.getName().startsWith(filePrefix))
                return true;
        return false;
    }};
File[] myFiles = directory.listFiles(filter);
if(myFiles.length < 1) {System.out.println("No files found");return;}
for (File file:myFiles) {
    try{
        System.out.println(readFileAsString(file));
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the java docs, theres a method called `lastModified` for a `File` object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29

Comment: I thought of this. But there could be thousand of files in folder and we might want to process only couple of files for a datetime. Is it correct to get all the file's meta data and then loop through all in memory to identify those couple by lastModified()?

Comment: To be honest, I dont think theres any other way to do so. At least none that I am aware of..

Comment: @rxs9014 No problem with scanning a few thousand files in a folder. File systems in today's operating systems are highly optimized and do their own caching of data.

Comment: However i recommend you do your own caching of lastModified(). If your files are used intensively (e.g. for logging) and you have a lot of them it might be that in an iteration a.lastModified() > b.lastModifed() and in another one a.lastModified() < b.lastModified() (because lastModified() will go to the file system for every call). One simple solution is to extend File and override lastModified() to return a cached value

Answer (score 0):

Use listFiles(FileFilter filter)

> Returns an array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and
>   directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname that
>   satisfy the specified filter.

Instead of list(FilenameFilter) where you can only filter on the name (string) of the file.
Use lastModified property in you "accept" implementation to check the date, and don't forget to add your old filter on the filename prefix!

Answer (score 0):

As others said, create a filter and in a loop access file metadata to get date of file.

To compare the date to see if it meets your criteria, use the [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class in Joda-Time to define a span of time between a pair of stop and start date-times. That class and its superclasses offer methods for comparing: contains, overlaps, isBefore, isAfter. You would call `contains` and pass a `DateTime` object constructed from the file's date-time metadata.